# MobileVLCKit slider Not working when i drag or action?

Tags: ios, iphone, vlc, uislider

Hi I am working with the MobileVLCKit 2.2.1 working fine.But When drag my slider it is not showing responce I am using VDLPlayerViewController for player from github.

```
- (IBAction)positionSliderAction:(UISlider *)sender
{
[self _resetIdleTimer];
[self performSelector:@selector(_setPositionForReal) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
 _setPosition = NO;
}  
- (void)_setPositionForReal
{
if (!_setPosition) {
    _mediaplayer.position = _positionSlider.value;
    _setPosition = YES;
}
}
```

But where I am missing Please help me out

Comment: Is the action connected to the slider in Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes it is connected in  Interface Builder The above method is also calling but not working

Comment: in the sample it is showing MLFile but I didn't find any file with that name What it is?where i can get that Please help me.

Comment: MLFile is a class of the MediaLibraryKit library but this is unrelated to the playback position. The above code is correct and is expected to work, even though there are nicer ways to coalesce events.

Comment: @feepk your right but i am using rtmp streaming but not live already recorded so is their any problem with the server side.I am using Red5 server

Comment: If suppose if i give http url then it is working fine but when i give rtmp then it is not working

Comment: Well, does VLC recognize the stream as seekable?

Comment: I think no any ways how to find the bitrate and framerate of video in player please help me

Comment: There are. Read the VLCMedia documentation.

Comment: i just found your blog But in that i didn't understood how to call api to get the metadata. do you have any document link please share with me please help me.

Comment: See the header file. This is the only documentation we have besides my blog.

Comment: @feepk When i change my deployment target 6.1 to 8.0 then it is showing lots of errors.I don't know why But i need my deployment target must be 8.0.How to achieve this